# CannotPullContainerError: pull image manifest has been retried 5 time(s): failed to resolve ref public.ecr.aws/j0m1s7l0/la-client-api:latest

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, docker-registry, amazon-ecr

I am trying to deploy an container for rest api along with a postgres container using terraform. The ECS task definition specifies the container image which is available is a public ECR repository. When I am applying the below terrafrom I got the error:

```
CannotPullContainerError: pull image manifest has been retried 5 time(s): failed to resolve ref public.ecr.aws/j0m1s7l0/la-client-api:latest: failed to do request: Head "https://public.ecr.aws/v2/j0m1s7l0/la-client-api/manifests/latest": dial tcp 99.83.145.10:443: i/o timeout
```

If I access public.ecr.aws/j0m1s7l0/la-client-api:latest I get the error: `{"errors":[{"code":"DENIED","message":"Not Authorized"}]}`. Now I am not sure if this is a problem with the repository not being publicly accessible or if the ECS service is unable to pull the image because of the network setting. I added the NAT gateway because the subnets of the ECS service are private. I spent two days now and I didn't figure out what is the issue in the terraform template. Any help in identifying the issue is really much appreciated. Many thanks

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.16"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

# Create Subnets in the VPC
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_az1" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/24"
  availability_zone       = "us-east-1a"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false # Disable auto-assigning public IPs
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_az2" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone       = "us-east-1b"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false # Disable auto-assigning public IPs
}


resource "aws_internet_gateway" "my_igw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
}

# Create a new Elastic IP for the NAT Gateway
resource "aws_eip" "nat_eip" {}

# Create a public subnet in your VPC
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_public" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.2.0/24"
  availability_zone       = "us-east-1c"  # Choose a different AZ for the public subnet
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true # Auto-assign public IPs
}

# Create a private route table for your private subnet(s)
resource "aws_route_table" "private_route_table" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
}

# Create the NAT Gateway in a public subnet
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "my_nat_gateway" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nat_eip.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.subnet_public.id
}

# Update the private subnet route table to route traffic through the NAT Gateway
resource "aws_route" "private_subnet_nat_gateway_route" {
  route_table_id         = aws_route_table.private_route_table.id
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"  # Route all traffic
  nat_gateway_id         = aws_nat_gateway.my_nat_gateway.id
}

# Associate the private route table with your private subnet(s)
resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_subnet1_association" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet_az1.id  # Replace with your private subnet ID
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private_route_table.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_subnet2_association" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet_az2.id  # Replace with your private subnet ID
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private_route_table.id
}

# resource "aws_eip" "my_eip" {}

# Create a Security Group for the Database
resource "aws_security_group" "db_security_group" {
  name        = "db-security-group"
  description = "Security group for the database"
  vpc_id        = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id

  # Define security group rules here
  # For example, allow incoming traffic on the database port
  ingress {
    from_port   = 5432
    to_port     = 5432
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] # TODO allow only traffic from ...
  }
}

# Security Group for ECS tasks
resource "aws_security_group" "my_ecs_security_group" {
  name        = "ecs-security-group"
  description = "Security group for ECS tasks"
  vpc_id        = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id

  # Allow incoming traffic from the ALB on port 8000 (or your application port)
  ingress {
    from_port   = 8000
    to_port     = 8000
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] # TODO
    # security_groups = [aws_security_group.my_alb_security_group.id]
  }

  # Allow outbound traffic 
  ingress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] # Allow all outbound traffic to all IP addresses
    # security_groups = [aws_security_group.my_alb_security_group.id]
  }
}

# Security Group for ALB
resource "aws_security_group" "my_alb_security_group" {
  name        = "alb-security-group"
  description = "Security group for ALB"
  vpc_id        = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id

  # Allow incoming traffic from anywhere (0.0.0.0/0) on port 80 (HTTP)
  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

# Create an RDS PostgreSQL instance for the database
resource "aws_db_instance" "la_client_api_database" {
  allocated_storage   = 20
  storage_type        = "gp2"
  engine              = "postgres"
  engine_version      = "15.3"
  instance_class      = "db.m5.large"
  db_name                = "la_client_api_db"
  username            = "postgres"
  password            = "postgres" # Replace with a secure password
  skip_final_snapshot = true
  publicly_accessible = true # TODO

#   vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.db_security_group.id]

  tags = {
    Name = "laclientapi"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "my_security_group" {
  name_prefix = "my-security-group-"
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  name = "my-cluster"
}

resource "aws_lb" "my_alb" {
  name               = "my-alb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  
  subnets = [
    aws_subnet.subnet_az1.id, # Subnet in Availability Zone 1
    aws_subnet.subnet_az2.id  # Subnet in Availability Zone 2
  ]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.my_alb_security_group.id]

  enable_cross_zone_load_balancing = "true"
  enable_deletion_protection = false
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "fargate_target_group" {
  # Target group configuration here
  name        = "fargate-target-group"
  port        = 8000 # Replace with the desired target port
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  target_type = "ip" # Use "ip" for Fargate tasks

  health_check {
    path                = "/"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    port                = "8000"
    interval            = 30
    timeout             = 5
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
  }
  
  # Ensure this target group is associated with the ALB
  depends_on = [aws_lb.my_alb]
}

# Create an ECS task definition for the API service
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "api_task" {
  family                   = "api-task"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs_execution_role.arn

  cpu     = "256"  # Specify the CPU value for the task in CPU units (e.g., 256)
  memory  = 512 # Specify the memory limit for the container in MiB
  
  container_definitions = jsonencode([{
    name  = "client-api-container"
    image = "public.ecr.aws/j0m1s7l0/la-client-api:latest" 
    
    portMappings = [{
      containerPort = 8000,
      hostPort      = 8000
    }]
    
    environment = [
      { name = "DATABASE_URL", value = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@${aws_db_instance.la_client_api_database.address}:5432/la_client_api_db" },
      { name = "ROCKET_ADDRESS", value = "0.0.0.0" },
      { name = "ROCKET_ENV", value = "release" },
    ]

    # Add an authentication block for Docker Hub with the access token
    authentication = [
      {
        credentials_parameter = "DOCKERHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN"
        authentication = "DOCKER"
        auth = "dckr_pat_e-doKHRHR8CKuRw4eWvirzzNYNk"
      }
    ]

    # volume {
    #   name      = "service-storage"
    #   host_path = "/ecs/service-storage"
    # }

    placement_constraints {
      type       = "memberOf"
      expression = "attribute:ecs.availability-zone in [us-east-1a, us-east-1b]"
    }

  }])
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "my_alb_listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.my_alb.arn
  port              = 80
  protocol          = "HTTP"
  
  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.fargate_target_group.arn
  }

  depends_on = [aws_lb.my_alb, aws_lb_target_group.fargate_target_group]
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "my_listener_rule" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.my_alb_listener.arn
  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.fargate_target_group.arn
  }

  priority = 1 # Set a priority lower than other rules

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/"]  # This path pattern will match all paths
    }
  }
}

# Create an ECS service for the API task
resource "aws_ecs_service" "api_service" {
  name            = "api-service"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.my_cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.api_task.arn
  desired_count = 1
  launch_type     = "FARGATE" # or EC2 
  # TODO: maybe specify LB to associate with the service
  network_configuration {
    subnets         =  [aws_subnet.subnet_az1.id, aws_subnet.subnet_az2.id]
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.my_ecs_security_group.id]
    assign_public_ip = true  # Add this line to assign a public IP
  }
  
  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.fargate_target_group.arn
    container_name   = "client-api-container"
    container_port   = 8000
  }

  depends_on = [aws_lb_target_group.fargate_target_group, aws_ecs_cluster.my_cluster, aws_db_instance.la_client_api_database]
}

# Define an IAM role for ECS task execution
resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_execution_role" {
  name = "ecs_execution_role"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [{
      Action = "sts:AssumeRole",
      Effect = "Allow",
      Principal = {
        Service = "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
      }
    }]
  })
}

# Attach the AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy policy to the execution role
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "ecs_execution_role_attachment" {
  name       = "ecs_execution_role_attachment"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
  roles      = [aws_iam_role.ecs_execution_role.name]
}

output "alb_dns_name" {
  value = aws_lb.my_alb.dns_name
}

# output "alb_public_ip" {
#   value = aws_lb.my_alb.load_balancer_type == "network" ? aws_lb.my_alb.ip_address : null
# }
```

I checked the terraform template several times. Same issue when the image is published in docker hub (`image = "outsidethecode/la:0.1"`)

Answer (score 1):

Your security group rule that has the comment of "allow all outbound traffic" is defined as an `ingress` rule, so it is actually allowing all **inbound** traffic. Your security group completely lacks an `egress` rule, so currently all outbound traffic is being blocked.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mark B. I've changed the word ingress to egress, it was my mistake. I applied the terraform again. However, I am still getting the error: `CannotPullContainerError: pull image manifest has been retried 5 time(s): failed to resolve ref public.ecr.aws/j0m1s7l0/la-client-api:latest: failed to do request: Head "https://public.ecr.aws/v2/j0m1s7l0/la-client-api/manifests/latest": dial tcp 99.83.145.10:443: i/o timeout`

Comment: I'm not seeing anything else wrong with the Terraform code. I would test by temporarily creating a small EC2 instance in the same subnet as the ECS service, and with the same security group, and see if it can pull that ECR image or otherwise access the Internet.

Comment: You might also try changing `assign_public_ip` to `false` in the `ecs_service`. Your current setting conflicts with the deployment of the service to private subnets, and I'm not sure how that will effect the routing of outbound requests.